# What does "numbling" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> It will be almost a month since you wrote to me and you have possibly
> forgotten your state of mind (I doubt it though). You seem the same as
> always, and being you, hate every minute of it. Don’t! Learn to say
> “Fuck You” to the world once in a while. You have every right to. Just
> stop thinking, worrying, looking over your shoulder, wondering,
> doubting, fearing, hurting, hoping for some easy way out, struggling,
> grasping, confusing, itching, scratching, mumbling, bumbling,
> grumbling, humbling, stumbling, **numbling**, rambling, gambling,
> tumbling, scumbling, scrambling, hitching, hatching, bitching,
> moaning, groaning, honing, boning, horse-shitting, hair-splitting,
> nit-picking, piss-trickling, nose sticking, ass-gouging,
> eyeball-poking, finger-pointing, alleyway-sneaking, long waiting,
> small stepping, evil-eyeing, back-scratching, searching, perching,
> besmirching, grinding, grinding, grinding away at yourself. Stop it
> and just

This is from the first part of [Sol LeWitt's letter to Eva Hesse](https://lettersofnote.com/2015/07/06/do/).
I couldn't find the meaning of numbling in any dictionaries. Is it a kind of wordplay? If so, what does it mean?

Comment: Where have you looked? I can't find a reference in a prestigious reference, but UD offers a definition. Probably non-standard.

Comment: For that matter, does anyone know the definition of "scumbling" in that quote? I'd guess it's just wordplay.

Comment: @Jurp - My sister went to art college so I know the word "scumbling". It's a painting technique

Comment: *Is it a kind of **wordplay**???!!!*

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica - Thanks! This is why I like the stacks - learn something new every day :)

Comment: It is just literary writing.

Comment: It's possibly a misreading, but could just be a nonsense word. As someone of Jewish background, LeWitt would be familiar with [Shm-reduplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shm-reduplication) which varies the initial letters of words to create new words and effects, and English-language nonsense verse uses similar techniques.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems simply to be a misreading of handwriting. Every word has a meaning. Even [scumbling](https://www.lexico.com/definition/scumble) is not a nonsense word.

[image: Extract of handwritten letter]

The first letter of both those words **could** be an *r* which would make *rambling* preceded by *rumbling.* In fact, to make the first three letters on that line *num* seems not to be possible as there are not enough strokes for it.

*Rumbling* seems far more likely. It doesn't appear anywhere else in that paragraph, and provides a neat bridge between *stumbling* (and all the other *-umbling* words) and *rambling.*

(The extract of the handwritten letter comes from the OP reference on [lettersofnote.com](https://lettersofnote.com/2015/07/06/do/))

Comment: Those first letters do look the same.  By Jove, I think you've got it!